# Workaround for Procedure Entry point Error

Tags: c++

I have ran into a strange behaviour when compilling my code. I have a gcc 13.2 installed with choco on windows and it has been working fine for the longest time but recently I had to compile assimp for my machine and, one of the recommendations was to use msys because it was better(I couldn't compile through the choco gcc) but I ran into this error.

```
main.exe - Entry Point Not Found
  
The procedure entry point \_ZNSt7\_ocx1118basic\_stringstreamlcSt1 1 char\_traitslcESalcEEC1 Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library D:\\Projects\\C++\\shooterOpenGl\\build\\main.exe. 0K
```

After some research, I realize that it was because the compiler was trying to find dlls in weird places and importing the wrong one. I managed to fix it with -static-libstdc++ and so the compilation was successful and I was able to get assimp working, all good.

But now it has messed up every compiler in my system(the gcc ones). Without adding the fix in every single project, the compiler leads to the above error and it is frustrating to do it over and over again.

It is a difficult thing to research online as well and the only solution I got is to directly put the .dll files into the executable directory.

So if someone understands this a lot better then can you make it so that I can have both the compilers and they do not conflict with each other?

I want msys so that I can compile some weird libraries in the future, therefore, the programs having scope limited only to the environments programs is no problem.

Comment: *"directly put the .dll files into the executable directory"* This is the correct solution. You'll need to do it anyway when distributing your programs, so might as well get used to do it (or configure your build system to do it for you). Alternatively, you can move your compiler's `bin` directory to be the first entry in the PATH, that should get rid of the error. (Doing any of the two means you no longer need `-static-whatever`.)

Comment: I do know that but this error comes even when I only have a simple hello world program with std::string library, and that is a headache. I do not have a problem with shipping my own made dlls but I do not want to send the standary library everytime.

Comment: Then use `-static-libstdc++` (and also `-static-libgcc`). What I'm saying is, if your build system neither copies the standard library DLLs nor passes those flags, it's not configured correctly. (Also, if you already ship some DLLs, I'd link the standard library dynamically. You don't lose anything by adding a few more DLLs, and the user gains the ability to update them if necessary.)

Comment: But I agree that it's desirable to be able to just do `g++ stuff.cpp` and quickly run the result without messing with PATH, and the solution to that is only have one compiler in your PATH, as the first entry. Having >1 compiler in PATH will cause issues most of the time. Consider using MSYS2 compiler from MSYS2 terminal and not adding it to PATH, their terminal overrides the PATH for itself to the correct value.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can you elaborate on the last part. So if you do not use msys compilers in the windows terminal they should not mess with your path right? If that is the case  then it should not be a problem for me. I installed mysys and did not add it to the path and was just using the msys gcc directly with the msys terminal. I just wanna learn how much can I stretch before I have to do static-libstdc++ thing.

Comment: Yes, unless you added MSYS2 to PATH manually, it shouldn't be there and shouldn't affect anything. Check the PATH to make sure it's not there, just in case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I checked in both the system path variables and the user path variables and there is nothing directing to the msys directory at all. Now I am in a deadlock.

Comment: Which compiler gives you those issues, the MSYS2 one or a different one? If MSYS2, then you're not running it from the MSYS2 terminal as you probably should. If a different version of GCC (or if you don't want the MSYS2 terminal), then your compiler is not the first directory in the PATH, as it should be.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It gives out the error on both. So I open msys mingw and compile a program there, the error happens when I execute the program. I do the same with my choco gcc compiler and it happens as well. Both of the gcc versions are 13.2.

Also, I appreciate you taking the time to reply to me.

Comment: Do you execute the program compiled in MSYS2 in the MSYS2 terminal as well?

Comment: Do you do something unusual when opening the MSYS2 terminal, such as passing extra flags to `msys2_shell.cmd`? If not, you likely have some dlls in `C:\Windows` (or subdirectories) that shouldn't be there (likely the libstdc++ one), delete them from there (you either put them there yourself, or used some low-quality installer that placed them there).

Comment: I checked in windows and well as the system32 directory and there is nothing called libstdc++. This is so weird.

Comment: Maybe the solution is, as you said, doing the -static-libstdc++ flag. Thank you for all the replies though, if you have any other methods then I would be happy to hear.

Comment: It should be working without the flag, I'm not sure what's going on. Can you record a video of yourself opening MSYS2, compiling and running the program from there? Include the output of `which g++` and `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Okay, I would try to do that when I am free.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Okay, I got it to start working. This was the stupidiest thing I have done. So, it seems that I had installed the gcc 4.3 from mingw's official installer and somewhere along the way I had changed the name to oldComp. The reason why it worked before was because choco gcc was always in system variables but when I reinstalled it, it was pushed to user variables and that's how it was messing things up. I ran programs  both in msys and choco gcc and they are working fine for now. 

Man, you screaming it's a PATH problem helped me look deeper. Thanks for helping my stupid ass.